# django geoposition map doesn't appear in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-geoposition

I'm using django-geoposition in a project and added it to my admin with a `GeopositionField()` in my `models.py`.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    position = GeopositionField()
```

When I access it, it shows the `lat, long` field, but not the google map.
There are no errors in the browser console.

I have the application configured correctly in `settings.py`: `INSTALLED_APPS` and `GEOPOSITION_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`.

**Django version==1.11.5**

What can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a django-geoposition problem. 
I found it and a workaround in:

https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/issues/83